# Allow non-admin accounts to query ntfs quota information

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, quota, disk-space-utilization

A technet article about Win2k NTFS quota settings[1] states:

> By default, only members of the Administrators group can view and change the quota settings. However, **the administrator can allow users to view quota settings**.

Does this still apply to Win2k8? If so, I couldn't find information on how to allow non-admins accounts to query quota information. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

It would be fine to grant extra privileges to a dedicated group, but adding the users to the local admin group is a no-go.

Edit: I'm trying to write a script which reports quota information. For security reasons, it should not run under an admin account.

[1] [Managing Disk Quotas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277427.aspx#EFAA)

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 2008 and 2008 R2 the preferred method of managing quotas is to use [FSRM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732431.aspx)

Provided your clients are Windows 7 (or iirc Vista) then the quota information will be available to your users through 'My Computer'.

Comment: I'm aware of FSRM, but the use of NTFS quotas is mandatory in my case. Also, I'm trying to query quota information programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to grant the "read permission" to the "msDS-QuotaContainer" for the user you want to run the script as.

> To view the NTDS Quotas container in the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in, you must enable Advanced Features on the View menu.

FYI you can use this in your script to query the quota:

```
dsget user <userDN> -part <partitionDN> -qlimit –qused
```

Example:

```
dsget user cn=bsmith,ou=HelpDesk,dc=fabrikam,dc=com –part dc=fabrikam,dc=com –qlimit –qused
```

source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/activedirectoryua/archive/2009/03/18/active-directory-quotas.aspx